# Indexing 2d lists in Python: Lengths in each dimension are not what I expect

Tags: python, list

If I create a 2d list:

```
In [1]: foo = [[None]*10]*5

In [2]: foo
Out[2]: 
[[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]

In [3]: len(foo)
Out[3]: 5
```

I would expect the list in the first element of foo to be accessed with `foo[0]` or `foo[0][:]`. Thus it's length is 10, as expected:

```
In [4]: len(foo[0][:])
Out[4]: 10
```

`type(foo[:][0])` returns "list". I would expect this to be a list constructed of the 0th elements from each "sublist" of foo. Thus it should be of length 5. However, this isn't the case:

```
In [5]: len(foo[:][0])
Out[5]: 10
```

What am I missing here/ what do I not understand?

Comment: lists of lists are not accessed as numpy arrays. `foo[:][0]` will just return the first list and have length 10. Why don;t you use numpy arrays and initialize your matrix using `numpy.zeros((5,10))` ?

Comment: `foo[:]` == `foo`, so `foo[:][0]` == `foo[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of list is not a matrix, it is a … list of list.

Let's decompose `foo[:][0]` :

- `foo` is a name pointing to a list
- `[:]` is a first "subscript access" to the list pointed by `foo`. Specifically you are getting a copy of the original list by slicing it with no  indexes given
- `[0]` is a second "subscript access" to the result of the first.

You are accessing the first element of a copy of foo.

Comment: Great answer thankyou! I thought it might be something simple, I just needed someone spoon feed me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try converting an array to numpy, it works much faster and is more convenient in accessing elements.

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.array([[None]*10]*5)
print(foo.shape)
print(len(foo[0, :]))#10
print(len(foo[:, 0]))#5
```

Answer (score -1):

In the source of list code,List is a structure with a double pointer which point to the space of array,and a length for list.To your list foo[:][0], foo[:] could writting like that foo[start:end], and , if you are not setting the value for start and end,it would auto set `-inf` and `inf`.So,foo[:] have all the sub_List.foo[:][0] is one of your sub_List.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).